# Highlight Row Differences in SSRS Report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report that compares duplicate values.  I want to compare rows with the same ID value and highlight the columns with differences.  Here is an example of my desired report.

[image]

What is the best way to achieve this in SSRS?

Here is a simplified example of the query used in my dataset

```
Select Diffs.ID
    , Diffs.Name
    , Diffs.Hobby
FROM
(
    SELECT a.ID
        , a.Name
        , a.Hobby
    FROM Table1 as a
    INNER JOIN Table2 as b
        ON a.ID = b.ID
    WHERE a.Name <> b.Name
        OR a.Hobby <> b.Hobby

    UNION 

    SELECT b.ID
        , b.Name
        , b.Hobby
    FROM Table1 as a
    INNER JOIN Table2 as b
        ON a.ID = b.ID
    WHERE a.Name <> b.Name
        OR a.Hobby <> b.Hobby

) AS Diffs
ORDER BY Diffs.ID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could create a group on id column (just suppress it, so it does't affect your report) then in background create a formula like

For Name column.

```
      =iif(CountDistinct(iif(isnothing(Fields!Name.Value) or 
Fields!Name.Value ="","x",Fields!Name.Value),"ID")<> 1 ,"Yellow","Transparent")
```

Comment: So close.  It just doesn't handle blanks.  I updated my example output to include a blank example.

Comment: Nice answer! I have seen this pattern before but focused my mind in other direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the cell background color property:

For Name column.

```
=IIF(Fields!ID.Value=PREVIOUS(Fields!ID.Value) and
Fields!Name.Value<>PREVIOUS(Fields!Name.Value),"Yellow","Transparent")
```

For Hobby column.

```
=IIF(Fields!ID.Value=PREVIOUS(Fields!ID.Value) and
Fields!Hobby.Value<>PREVIOUS(Fields!Hobby.Value),"Yellow","Transparent")
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks.  That is close, but I think it would only highlight the second row.  Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be a Next function.

Comment: Can you share the query you are using in your dataset?

Comment: I added a simplified version of my query.  Thanks.

Comment: @Matt, did you try to use the Kostya solution? it should work, If that is not the case I'll post an answer.

Comment: I am testing it now.  It is pretty close.  I am just trying to figure out how to handle blank values.  In my solution, I want to highlight the column if one is blank and the other not.